# swift vapor json response to array

Tags: arrays, swift, elasticsearch, swift3, vapor

using swift vapor and elasticsearch, got a response like:

`{
    "_shards": {
        "failed": 0,
        "successful": 5,
        "total": 5
    },
    "hits": {
        "hits": [
            {
                "_id": "3",
                "_index": "items_v1",
                "_score": 1.2029922,
                "_source": {
                    "property1": "test",
                    "property2": "another test",
                    ...
                },
                "_type": "item"
            },
            ...`

inside "hits" -> "hits" -> "_source" I got all the properties of my model "Item". How can I create an array of Items "[Item]" from this json response?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Parse your response in this way, so there will be no crashes if some value will not be sent.

```
if let dict = response as? [String : Any] {
    if let hits = dict["hits"] as? [String : Any] {
        if let hitArray = hits["hits"] as? [[String : Any]] {
            for hit in hitArray {
                if let source = hit["_source"] {
                    arrayOfItems.append(Item(with: source))
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Int your Item class create init method, where you will initialize item's properties.

```
init(with dict: [String : Any]) {

    if let property1 = dict["property1"] as? Int {
        self.property1 = property1
    }

    super.init()
}
```

Comment: okay got it working with this approach, thought there would be a more elegant solution, maybe a one liner using vapor. But obviously not. Anyway, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Small enhancement, use a guard statement to avoid the nested ifs...

```
guard
  let dict = response as? [String : Any],
  let hits = dict["hits"] as? [String : Any],
  let hitArray = hits["hits"] as? [[String : Any]]
else
{ throw Abort}

for hit in hitArray {
   if let source = hit["_source"] {
        arrayOfItems.append(Item(with: source))
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this! I assume that you get the Response and that response in saved in response variable

```
    var myarray = [String]()
    let hitDict = response["hits"] as! [String:AnyObject]

    let hitArray = hitDict["hits"] as! Array

    let someDict = hitArray[0] as! [String:AnyObject]
    let sourcDict = someDict["_source"] as! [String:AnyObject]

    let property1 = sourcDict["property1"] as! String
    let property2 = sourcDict["property2"] as! String
    myarray.append(property1)
    myarray.append(property2)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var myArray = [String:String]()

//response from try drop.client.get(…)
let bodyReceived = responseFirebaseAssigned?.body.bytes

//JSON object made of bodyReceived
let JsonFirebase:JSON? 

     for val in JsonFirebase?.object ?? [:]{

        let valKey = val.key.string
        let valValue = val.value.string
        arrayFB[valKey!] = valValue
        print("arrayFB is \(arrayFB)")
    }
```